# Using the armV5 compiler in keil with c99 and cpp11

Tags: c++, c++11, arm, c99, keil

I have a mixed project in Keil IDE with c and cpp files. I want to compile the cpp files with the cpp11 standard, but when I set the --cpp11 in the misc controls it compiles the C files as cpp files (and obviously that causes a lot of compilation errors) the c files needs to be compiles in the c99 standard.
I ended up setting the --cpp11 flag just on a specific group to work around the issue.
But I'm wondering if there is a way to set both of the rules (--cpp11 and --c99) to the entire project?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't end up finding a way to use the compiler with any c version and cpp11 combined.

The only why to use the cpp11 features (FYI not all of them are implemented in armV5 compiler), you need to set the --cpp11 flag in the mist control option after right-clicking on either a group containing only cpp files or on the specific files. To get to the misc control option you need to right-click the file or folder and press the c/c++ tab.